# net.rim.device.api.io.file.FileIOException: File system out of resources in blackberry

Tags: exception, blackberry

Below code throws **net.rim.device.api.io.file.FileIOException: File system out of resources**  this exception.

Can anyone tell me how it happens?

```
public Bitmap loadIconFromSDcard(int index) {

    FileConnection fcon = null;
    Bitmap icon = null;
    InputStream is=null;
    try {

        fcon = (FileConnection) Connector.open(Shikshapatri.filepath + "i"
                + index + ".jpg", Connector.READ);
        if (fcon.exists()) {
            byte[] content = new byte[(int) fcon.fileSize()];
            int readOffset = 0;
            int readBytes = 0;
            int bytesToRead = content.length - readOffset;
            is = fcon.openInputStream();
            while (bytesToRead > 0) {
                readBytes = is.read(content, readOffset, bytesToRead);
                if (readBytes < 0) {
                    break;
                }
                readOffset += readBytes;
                bytesToRead -= readBytes;
            }

            EncodedImage image = EncodedImage.createEncodedImage(content,
                    0, content.length);
            image = resizeImage(image, 360, 450);
            icon = image.getBitmap();

        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Error:" + e.toString());
    } finally {
        // Close the connections
        try {
            if (fcon != null)
                fcon.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }
        try {
            if (is != null)
                is.close();
                is = null;

        } catch (Exception e) {
        }
    }

    return icon;
}
```

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 1):

Check this BB dev forum post - http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Java-Development/File-System-Out-of-Resources/m-p/105597#M11927

Basically you should **guaranteedly** close all connections/streams as soon as you don't need them, because there is a limited number of connection (be it a file connection or http connection) handles in OS. If you execute several `loadIconFromSDcard()` calls at the same time (from different threads) consider redesign the code to call them sequentially.

**UPDATE:**

To avoid errors while reading the `content` just use the following:

```
byte[] content = IOUtilities.streamToBytes(is);
```

And since you don't need file connection and input stream any longer just close them right after reading the `content` (before creating `EncodedImage`):

```
is.close();
is = null;    // let the finally block know there is no need to try closing it
fcon.close();
fcon = null;  // let the finally block know there is no need to try closing it
```

Minor points:

Also in the `finally` block it is worth set `fcon = null;` explicitly after you close it, I believe this can help old JVMs (BB uses Java 1.3 - rather old one) to decide quicker that the object is ready to be garbage collected.

I also believe that the order you close streams in the `finally` block may be important - I'd change to close `is` first and then `fcon`.

Comment: Arhimed, Can you tell me how i close all connection i already close connection and stream in finally block

Comment: For instance, are you sure you always call `is.close()`? Looks like if you get an error while reading `content`, then you don't close `is` at all.

Comment: Hello Arhimed, Sorry For inconvenience Now i have update my code. yet i m getting this error.

Comment: Please see the UPDATE section.

Comment: Hello Arhimed, I have try your updated code still i am getting this exception actually i successfully load 45 images from SDCard but after then it gives this error. I appreciate for your help.

Comment: How exactly do you call `loadIconFromSDcard()`? Are all the calls in the only thread (calls are executed sequentially)? Does the app do any other file-system/networking activity at the same time?

Comment: HELLO ,All calls are executed sequentially i.e. Bitmap headingimg = loadIconFromSDcard(Shikshapatri.position);

Comment: Sorry, then I just have no ideas... Maybe just try to set some delay between `loadIconFromSDcard()` calls (to give the system some time to "restore" itself) and see if the issue still happens?